# What does it mean when saying: "it reduces bias by alternating" in the following?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

I saw this part in some **Programming Language Book**:

> Understanding the default rounding rules In British primary schools

> for children aged 5 to 11, pupils are taught to round up if the
> decimal part is .5 or higher and round down if the decimal part is
> less. Let's explore if C# follows the same primary school rule:
>
> 1. At the bottom of the Main method, add statements to declare and assign an array of  double values, convert each of them to an integer,
>    and then write the result to the  console, as shown in the following
>    code:

```
double[] doubles = new[] 
 { 9.49, 9.5, 9.51, 10.49, 10.5, 10.51 };
foreach (double n in doubles)
{
 WriteLine($"ToInt({n}) is {ToInt32(n)}");
}
```

2. Run the console application and view the result, as shown in the following output:

```
ToInt(9.49) is 9
ToInt(9.5) is 10
ToInt(9.51) is 10
ToInt(10.49) is 10
ToInt(10.5) is 10
ToInt(10.51) is 11
```

> We have shown that the rule for rounding in C# is subtly different
> from the primary school rule: • It always rounds down if the decimal
> part is less than the midpoint .5. • It always rounds up if the
> decimal part is more than the midpoint .5. • It will round up if the
> decimal part is the midpoint .5 and the non-decimal part is odd,  but
> it will round down if the non-decimal part is even.
>
> This rule is known as Banker's Rounding, and it is preferred because
> it reduces **bias by alternating** when it rounds up or down. Sadly,
> other languages such as JavaScript use the primary school rule...

I haven't found what the following section means:

> and it is preferred because
> it reduces **bias by  alternating** when it rounds up or down

Would anybody explain it to me?

Comment: Do you know the meaning of "bias" and "alternating"?

Answer (score 1):

**Bias** is the property (of a system, of a computer program, of a person) to favor one thing over another. Really the word means an *imbalance*. It is not necessarily a bad thing; the materials that make up computer chips must be properly biased in order to work, for example.

In this case the "primary school" method is claimed to be *biased* because the value `x.5`, which is precisely the midpoint between `x` and `x+1`, is always rounded up. Over a large data set this can increase the overall values and drive the average higher than it really is. "Banker's rounding" *alternates* whether `x.5` is rounded up or down, which causes this bias to go away—the average should not be artificially increased.

Answer (score 1):

> and it is preferred because it reduces bias by alternating when it rounds up or down

*bias* in the above fragment takes the following meaning in [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bias).

> the fact that information is not correct because of the method used in collecting or presenting it:

> There is a need to build in safeguards against statistical bias.

As a 0.5 increment from an integer leads to the mid point between that integer and the next, **consistent** rounding **up** would lead to **inaccuracies** in subsequent results.

*it reduces bias by alternating* means this method alternates between rounding up and rounding down and hence reduces inaccuracies in subsequent results.